# Created a file called "keys.py" where I have four variables which store strings of private access keys

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, python-module

When I imported "keys", PyCharm says the variables are an unsolved reference?
Keys.py code:

```
consumer_key = 'rXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
consumer_secret ='6XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_secret = 'XXXXXXXXX'
```

Main script code:

```
 import tweepy
 import keys
```

## OAuth using the provided keys and tokens

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
```

## Creation of interface, with authentication

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

keyphrase = 'Testing'
for keyphrase in api.mentions_timeline():
    api.update_status('@{} Testing 
successful!'.format(keyphrase.user.screen_name))
```

The OAuth using the provided keys and tokens keeps giving me a "unresolved reference" error. I've already imported the keys.py file correctly, so i'm confused as to why its doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the module name when referring to names defined in another module:

```
import keys
...
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys.consumer_key, keys.consumer_secret)
                           ^^^^^              ^^^^^
```

Alternatively, you can import the names directly into the current module's namespace, but I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `import keys` you should put `from keys import consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret`.

You could also put `from keys import *`, or as the other poster mentioned you can access them by leaving your import as is and writing `keys.VARIABLE_NAME`.